# ServiceStack AutoQuery ordering

Tags: servicestack

I am using AutoQuery which makes writing services very simple. One of my queries needs to order descending by value X and then ascending by value Y. It appears that in AutoQuery you can order everything ascending or descending but not a combination.

To get around this I added custom properties to indicate my states something like this:

```
    // Custom fields to determine sort order
    public bool? IsState1 { get; set; }
    public bool? IsState2 { get; set; }
```

This does work however I was wondering if it was possible to do this natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) lets you specify multiple Order By's where you can sort in reverse order by prepending a `-` before the field name, e.g:

```
?orderBy=X,-Y
```

Comment: That is super awesome. Is that in the documentation?

Comment: @Telavian thought it was before, [but it is now](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#sort-specific-fields-in-reverse-order) :)